# Want to implement login security using those random number generator security dongles

Tags: security

I don't know what these are called, so I will explain as best I can what we want to do:

We want to implement a secure log-in system so that when logging in we want to ask for a number that is generated on a small device that is carried with the person at all times.

I understand these devices work by relying on an algorithm that generates random numbers based on the current time.  The same method is used on the sever side.  They both independently generate the same numbers, since their clocks are in sync, and because its the same algorithm.  When the user enters this number they should match.

Where can one buy these security dongles?  What is this authentication method even called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of [RSA SecurID](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156) as a supplier of two-factor authentication solutions.

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds to the same URL.

Comment: Fastest gun in the west - this time :)

Answer (score 1):

One name for one species of the gadgets you are looking for is [RSA SecurID](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156).

Answer (score 1):

Our company used to use Safeword Tokens.  Google the name, and you'll have a host of places to buy them from.

http://www.google.com/search?q=safeword+token&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

However, an even COOLER method of authentication is [Phone Factor](http://www.phonefactor.com/), which we switched to when we went away from SafeWord..